# Google Apps Script function executing twice for one onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, function, google-apps-script

I am trying to add a UI feature to a google sheet that allows users to update info. The script functions properly but for whatever reason is executing twice. Here's the code:

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.google.com/css/maia.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <br />
    Username: 
    <input id="username" value="">
    <br />
    Select the Country: 
    <select id="country">
      <option value="USA" selected="selected">USA</option>
      <option value="CAN">Canada</option>
      <option value="MEX">Mexico</option>
    </select>
  </body>
<hr/>

<button id="runBtn">Update Country</button>
<button onclick="google.script.host.close()">Close</button> 

<script>
  document.getElementById("runBtn").addEventListener("click",function r(event){
    // document elements that we will pass to updateCountry function
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var e = document.getElementById("country");
    var country = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    // run updateCountry function
    google.script.run.updateCountry(username, country);
    google.script.host.close();
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(event.type, r)
    event.stopPropagation();
  })
</script> 

</html>
```

Google script (javascript)

```
function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').setHeight(100);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Update Country');
}

function updateCountry(username, country){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 

  // appends row to sheet with updated User country
  updateUserInfo(username, country);
}
```

Could someone please advise how to get the the function to run only once? Is this the result of a bubbling issue? I've tried event.stopPropagation() but that does not seem to help.

**UPDATE:**
The updateUserInfo() function also had variables referencing

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("AnotherTab");
```

I've sinced move that function into updateCountry() and the double execution (appendRow) has stopped.

Comment: What does `updateUserInfo` function do? I know as per comment it appends the data but could you please share the code that you're using for that?

Comment: It's the problem fixed? How is it running twice? Is it prompting the dialog twice?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to run at first.  I had to remove some curly quotation marks in it that the script editor didn't like.  Anyway I modified a little and now it works and doesn't run twice.

html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <br>
    Username: 
    <input type="text" id="username" value="ldldldldldl" /><br />
    Select the Country:<select id="country">
      <option value="USA" selected="selected">USA</option>
      <option value="CAN">Canada</option>
      <option value="MEX">Mexico</option>
    </select>

<hr/>

<button id="runBtn">Update Country</button>
<button onclick="google.script.host.close()">Close</button> 

<script>
$(function(){
  document.getElementById("runBtn").addEventListener("click",function r(event){
    console.log('flag1');
    var username=$('#username').val();
    console.log(username);
    console.log('flag2');
    var country=$('#country').val();
    console.log('flag3');
    console.log(country);
    google.script.run.updateCountry(username, country);
    google.script.host.close();
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(event.type, r)
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('exit');
  })
  });
</script> 
 </body>
</html>
```

GS:

```
function runOne() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('aq7');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html,'Update Country');
}

function updateCountry(username, country){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.appendRow([username,country]);
  Logger.log(username);
  Logger.log(country);
}
```